# Trying to addActionListener to a JButton but does not work?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to add an actionlistener to my button, but I keep getting an error and I dont understand what to do.

code:

```
class gaaopp implements ActionListener {
     @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if (dir != 'D') {
                dir = 'U';
        }}}

opp.addActionListener(new gaaopp());
```

I have defined opp in the constructor of a class

```
JButton opp = new JButton("Opp");
kontrol.add(opp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedNameJava(1610612976)
Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderNameJava(1610612976)
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclarationJava(1610612976)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `opp.addActionListener(new gaaopp());` You can't just add the statement randomly in your code after your class definition. That statement should be moved AFTER the statement where you create the button. Also, class names should be meaningful and start with an upper case character. Learn by example. All the classes in the JDK follow this standard.

Comment: @camickr, thank you mate, its my first day programing in JDK, so everything seems so weird. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: *"... its my first day programing in JDK"*.  Really?  They put you on writing a Swing UI tool as you first ever Java program?  I think you probably should be doing some basic Java programming tutorials first!